# Is it possible to highlight words used in a input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

End goal. Type input into an area. have a second area highlight that word when typed.

I have two input areas. One holds a list of individual words, one word per line. The second input text will be entered. I'd like to highlight words from the initial list individually when they are typed within the second input. Is this possible?

I have my code pushing data into the areas I want but not sure how to go about highlighting individual words in a area different from the area input is being entered.

```
<textarea class="col-md-3" id="inputArray1" rows="20" cols="10" placeholder="Input1"></textarea>
<textarea class="col-md-3" id="inputArray2" rows="20" cols="10" placeholder="Input2"></textarea>

//holding input values for text area
var InputVar = document.getElementById("inputArray1").value;
var InputVar2 = document.getElementById("inputArray2").value;

//holding output values for text area
var OutputVar = document.getElementById("outputArray1");
var OutputVar2 = document.getElementById("outputArray2");

// takes string and breaks into substring array of words
var SplitString = InputVar.split(/[\s]+/g);

//displays list of words in 2nd text area
OutputVar.value = SplitString;
```

Comment: You cannot highlight (that is apply HTML tags to) something in `textarea`. This element is text-only.

Comment: If you want to highlight text in a `textarea`, you have to use an overlay. Here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/lonekorean/pen/gaLEMR) to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks for the input. So there is no way to highlight words dynamically that meet certain requirements?

Comment: Making it dynamic isn't the difficulty. Once you have figured out how to highlight certain text, then you can work on making the highlighting criteria dynamic. It's possible, you just have to break up the problem into smaller parts.

Comment: Do you want to be able to dynamically add words to both "inputs"?

Comment: The first list won't change once the words are added I just want to be able to highlight words from that list once they are typed into the second area

Comment: Given that you will not edit the "first" list, does it have to be a textarea?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a text area, but it needs to be able to hold multi line output.